# "An error occurred while getting provider information from the database" while deploying Code First

Tags: ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-4, connection-string

I'm getting the following error while deploying my ASP.NET MVC 4 application (Code First) to IIS:

"An error occurred while getting provider information from the database.
This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct."

I've been looking around for answers, but none of the situations matches mine:

I got 2 projects

- BackEnd (DataAccess with Code First + WCF services)
- FrontEnd MVC 4 application (only service references to WCF services)

On my local IIS + SQL Server 2008 it works fine. Even if I change connectionstring to production database everything works as espected.

The problem occurs when deploying the BackEnd + FrontEnd to IIS.

The only connection string that accesses db is located in my BackEnd application:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="fromMail" value="xxx@gmail.com" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TTCWestelDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.2.14\SQLSERVER2008;Initial Catalog=TTCWestel001;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXX;Password=XXX" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="3600" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData= "c:\Temp\WCFTracesTTCWestel.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>

</configuration>
```

Any help appreciated!!

Thanks

Micclo